# Express-form (Node.js) <ServerResponse> has no method 'local'

Tags: node.js, express

Using Node v0.8.8 with Express ~3.0.0rc3 (for the record, here is my packages.json's content) :

```
{
  "name": "application-name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~3.0.0rc3",
    "jade": "*",
    "ejs": "~0.8.2",
    "express-partials": "0.0.5",
    "connect-flash": "~0.1.0",
    "connect-redis": "~1.4.1",
    "validator": "~0.4.11",
    "express-validator": "~0.2.4",
    "express-form": "~0.6.2"
  }
}
```

And I'm getting the following error while trying to do a POST to validate a login form.

```
TypeError: Object #<ServerResponse> has no method 'local'
    at /Users/nblavoie/Documents/projets/erphdfnode/node_modules/express-form/lib/form.js:32:15
    at callbacks (/Users/nblavoie/Documents/projets/erphdfnode/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:165:11)
    at param...
```

Is there something wrong with my controller? Here is the code :

```
var routes = function(app)
{
    var form = require("express-form"),
        field = form.field;

    app.post("/login",
        form(
            field("courriel").trim().isEmail(),
            field("password").trim().notEmpty()
        ),
        function(req, res)
        {
            if (!req.form.isValid) {
                renderLogin("Courriel ou de mot de passe incorrect.", req);
            } else {
                console.log("OK!!!!!");
            }
        }
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`express-form` does not support `express` 3.0.

Check out [this issue](https://github.com/dandean/express-form/pull/35) for more information.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any advice on how to check for this kind of problem? Do you search the commits history of the package to find these kind of solutions?

Comment: The recursive packages model implemented by `npm` does not allow one to require a specific framework version in their package so that `npm` will warn you about incompatible versions. Still, some packages do refer a specific `express` version in their `package.json` file. Unfortunately, `express-form` is not among these. `express` v3 is not backwards-compatible with the `express` v2; and the `express-form` libraries accept an `express` object from your code and are trying to perform v2-specific tasks on it, that's it.

Comment: Basically, you will only face this kind of problem with `express` versions. The difference between `node`, `express` and other libraries is that depending library refers to (and **require**s) its dependencies, refers to a specific `node` engine version (which is what `engines` field in `package.json` is for), but accepts an arbitrary framework object from outside.